# Privacy Nutrition Labels are not showing up in privacy report for a sample iOS app built using my third party SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, swift-package-manager

I work at a company that distributes its third-party iOS SDK to its customers. As per WWDC2023, Apple has made it mandatory for third-party SDKs to include PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy manifest file which contains the Privacy Nutrition Labels. I have added this file to my SDK and we have a custom build script to generate .zip file to distribute. The manifest file is getting added in .zip file, but when we use this SDK to build a sample iOS application, when I generate the archive file and try to generate a privacy report for this archive, it says " The archive does not contain any PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files ". Can you please suggest what could be that I am doing wrong?

Apple WWDC2023 video for third-party SDKs - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060/

[zip structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmGBq.png)

[error message in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCxxC.png)

I have to manually place this file without using Xcode and it didn't work. Need help to make sure the manifest file content gets included in privacy report of the sample iOS app that uses this SDK.

Comment: Hi @venugopal-reddy,
Have you tried to place privacy manifest near your static library?
VPProtectSPM.xcframework -> ios-arm64 -> PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

Comment: yes, Its reflecting in the build.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add appropriate targets to the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file?

I fixed the same error by doing so.